# Creating multiprocessing.Pool pools every hour

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a program in place that follows logic like this:

At the start of every hour, multiple directories receive a file that is continuously fed data. I'm developing a simple program that can read all the files simultaneously and abstracted the tailing/reading part into a function, lets call it 'tail' for now. The external program feeding the data doesn't always run smoothly. Sometimes a file will come in late, sometimes the next hour will hit and the program still feeds the stale file data. I can't afford to lose the data. My solution looks something like this using multiprocessing.pool using pseudo code in parts of it:

```
def process_data(logfile):
    num_retries = 5
    while num_retries > 0:
        if os.path.isfile(logfile):
            for record in tail(logfile):
                do_something(record)
        else:
            num_retries -= 1
        time.sleep(30)

def tail(logfile):
    logfile = open(logfile, 'r')
    logfile.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        line = logfile.readline()
        if line:
            wait_time = 0
            yield line
        else:
            if wait_time >= 360:
                break
            wait_time += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = sys.argv[1]
    next_hour = None

    while True:
        logdirs = glob.glob("/opt/logs/plog*")

        current_date = datetime.now()
        current_hour = current_date.strftime('%H')
        current_format = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H")

        logfiles = [logdir + '/some/custom/path/tofile.log' for logdir in logdirs]

        if not next_hour:
            next_hour = current_date + timedelta(hours=1)


        if current_hour == next_hour.strftime('%H') or current_hour == start_time:
            start_time = None
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
            pool.map(process_data, logfiles)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()

        next_hour = current_date + timedelta(hours=1)
        time.sleep(30)
```

Here's what I'm observing when I have logging implemented at the process level:

- all files in each directory are getting read appropriately
- when the next hour hits, there's a delay of 360s (6 minutes) before the next set of files get read
- so if hour 4 ends, a new pool doesn't get created for hour 5 until processes for hour 4 finish

What I'm looking for: I'd like to keep using multiprocessing, but can't figure out why the code inside the main while loop doesn't go through until the previous Pool of processes finishes. I have tried the hourly logic for other examples without multiprocessing and have had it work fine. I'm lead to believe that this has to do with the Pool class and hoping to get advice on how to make it so that even while the previous Pool is active, I can create a new Pool for the new hour and begin processing new files even if it means this creates a ton of processes.

Comment: How does `next_hour()` work?

Comment: That was just to simplify the code. What's actually happening is that inside the main while loop, I capture what the current hour is in a variable current_hour and what the next hour is in next_hour. Then the actual if statement checks whether current_hour == next_hour so that processes get only spun up when the next hour has begun.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the full code, but it seems like processing the files takes a while and by calling `pool.join()` you are waiting on it and basically blocking the next hour's processing.

Comment: I've edited the code a bit to make the if statement more clear. I also tried running the program without pool.join() and am seeing the same result

Comment: You should include the real code you're using. This code seems to be updating `next_hour` every single time the loop runs so it will never actually be equal to `current_hour`. That said, it seems like you are calculating `next_hour` by adding one hour to the current time. You need to zero out the minutes and seconds as well or you'll get an offset that will just keep growing with every loop.

Comment: Ok I've updated it with my current code. Because I use .strftime('%H') in the comparison, my code correctly checks whether the hour is new, correct? Thank you

Comment: No. You should only update `next_hour` after actually running the code, otherwise you might miss schedules. Initialize it once before the loop and then only update it when you actually run `multiprocessing.map()`. If you want multiple batches to be able to run at once (if a single batch takes more than an hour), remove the `.join()` call.